# Scraping links from the first page of Google using Kivy

Tags: python, web-scraping, kivy

I'm making a scraper/web crawler using Kivy when I run the code it works but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is Pythonic because all the language I can find is about using the Kivy library. I'm unsure about putting the functions to bind the widgets to inside the build method. Is there a better way?

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        c = CustomLayout()
        root.add_widget(c)

        search_term = TextInput(
            text='',
            size_hint=(.5, .05),
            pos=(250, 15))
        c.add_widget(search_term)

        def on_enter(self):
            scrape = Scrape(search_term.text, ['user_agent','chrome'])
            scrape.get_goog_links()
        get_links = Button(
            text='Get links',
            size_hint=(.5, .10),
            pos=(20, 20))
        root.add_widget(get_links)
        get_links.bind(on_press=on_enter)

        return root
```

Comment: You know Google has bot protection against this kind of thing, right?

Comment: @Quill It still works though ;).

Comment: Not saying it doesn't, just might not be effective when you ramp up the speeds.